# downloading a large file from public link

Tags: wget

I am trying to download a 55GB zipped file from `https://gofile.io/` as someone has given me a public link. I have tried through wget command but it download a file with the same name but size-wise it is only in KBs. How to tackle this issue?

Comment: maybe the remote file is corrupted

Comment: No, I have downloaded it once by clicking on it, but now I am doing it on a server which has no graphical OS, so i need to do it through commands, and thats what I can not do ..

Comment: Please try opening *file with the same name but size-wise it is only in KBs.* using text editor and check if there is any intelligible text, if yes write what it is